# Why are these 2.9 ChartJS bar charts different?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Using ChartJS 2.9.4, why are these 2 charts different?

```
<div >
    <canvas id="topcanvas"></canvas>
    <canvas id="bottomcanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

```
        var leftdata = {
          labels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
          datasets: [{
              label: "A",
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)',
              data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 1],
              xAxisID: "A"
            },
            {
              label: "B",
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)',
              data: [14, 19, 6, 2, 4],
              xAxisID: "B"
            }
          ]
        };
        
        var rightdata = {
          labels: [0, 1, 2, 3, "4", 5], // the #4 being a string is the only difference
          datasets: [{
              label: "A",
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)',
              data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 1],
              xAxisID: "A"
            },
            {
              label: "B",
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)',
              data: [14, 19, 6, 2, 4],
              xAxisID: "B"
            }
          ]
        };

        var options = {
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                id: "A",
                display: false,
                barPercentage: 1.25,
                ticks: {
                  max: 4 
                }
              },
              {
                id: "B",
                display: false,
                stacked: true,
                offset: true,
                barPercentage: 1.25,
                ticks: {
                  max: 4
                }
              },
              {
                display: true,
                ticks: {
                  autoSkip: false,
                  max: 5 
                }
              }
            ],

            yAxes: [{
              id: "bar-y-axis1",
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
              }
            }]

          }
        };

        var leftctx = document.getElementById("topcanvas").getContext("2d");
        new Chart(leftctx, {
          type: 'bar',
          data: leftdata,
          options: options
        });
        var rightctx = document.getElementById("bottomcanvas").getContext("2d");
        new Chart(rightctx, {
          type: 'bar',
          data: rightdata,
          options: options
        });
```

[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpebkf8h/1/)[image: The different Charts]

Comment: This is a good question. I've always been terribly frustrated by the ChartJS documentation.

Comment: It could be that there's something that checks to see if the `labels` list *looks* like a list of numbers, and then uses the values to compute widths for each bar in the datasets. When one label isn't a number, that may mess up that computation. But who knows, the source base is enormous so good luck finding the code involved.

Comment: It also shifts the width if all values in the array are strings. Strange.

Comment: What's funny is that it seems that only 4 has to exist as an integer to get the desired behavior. If you change it to a floating point number, you get the bottom chart. If you change literally any other label, everything is fine. But if you make 4 anything but an integer, it makes the chart go all wonky.

Comment: Well note that `4` corresponds to the 5th value in the data arrays; that is, you have five values, so labels 0 through 4 correspond to the values. I mean, that sure seems like a bug to me, but it's the only interesting thing about that position in the `labels` array. (Also, it's important to note that that's kind-of an older release. Of course the 3.x  releases have a *significantly* different API.)

Comment: Yes I think the problem is that you have 6 labels and only define 5 x axis values, if you change the labels to `labels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, the charts are the same, still weird tho

Comment: @axtck Yeah, am trying to build an overlapping histogram using their bar chart. Unfortunately to accomplish that, my axis needs more labels than I have bars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is fixed in v3 of the lib

```js
var leftdata = {
  labels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  datasets: [{
      label: "A",
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 1],
      xAxisID: "A"
    },
    {
      label: "B",
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)',
      data: [14, 19, 6, 2, 4],
      xAxisID: "B"
    }
  ]
};

var rightdata = {
  labels: [0, 1, 2, 3, "4", 5], // the #4 being a string is the only difference
  datasets: [{
      label: "A",
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 1],
      xAxisID: "A"
    },
    {
      label: "B",
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)',
      data: [14, 19, 6, 2, 4],
      xAxisID: "B"
    }
  ]
};

var options = {
  scales: {
    A: {
      display: false,
      barPercentage: 1.25,
      ticks: {
        max: 4
      },
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    B: {
      display: false,
      stacked: true,
      offset: true,
      barPercentage: 1.25,
      position: 'bottom',
      ticks: {
        max: 4
      }
    },
    x: {
      display: true,
      ticks: {
        autoSkip: false,
        max: 5
      }
    },

    y: {
      id: "bar-y-axis1",
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }

  }
};

var leftctx = document.getElementById("topcanvas").getContext("2d");
new Chart(leftctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: leftdata,
  options: options
});
var rightctx = document.getElementById("bottomcanvas").getContext("2d");
new Chart(rightctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: rightdata,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <canvas id="topcanvas"></canvas>
  <canvas id="bottomcanvas"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.js" integrity="sha512-opXrgVcTHsEVdBUZqTPlW9S8+99hNbaHmXtAdXXc61OUU6gOII5ku/PzZFqexHXc3hnK8IrJKHo+T7O4GRIJcw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: Well that's good news at least. Upgrading to v3 was something I was trying to avoid due to some time constraints I face, but a working feature is better than no feature at all. I'll give the question a little more time, but this is likely my answer.

Comment: For anyone who happens upon this page, here is my ChartJS 3.0 verion with the labels aligned correctly [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mortalapeman/ube3rfq1/6/)